# Use Naive Bayes to label unlabeled data

Tags: naive-bayes, labeling, bayes-optimal-classifier

I have an Excel file that includes all product information (web scraped from Zalando) of 10k dresses. So for each dress/line I have multiple features available (brand, color, neckline, length...)

I would like to include a new column "style" that has 5 different possible values (formal, sporty...). I was considering to manually label about 500 dresses and then use Naive Bayes Classifier to label the remaining 9500 dresses. It won't be perfect, but i do believe some features are highly correlated with e.g 'sporty' such as 'Nike' or 'sweatshirt fabric'.

What is your opinion on this? Are there better ways?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Would you base the model on the $500$ dresses you label?

Comment: Hi Dave and thank you! Yes i would manually label these 500 dresses and then consider these as my training set (i think?).

Comment: This is how I interpreted Bayes to work: Say most of the dresses I manually labeled as "sporty" include the features 'Nike', 'short dress' and 'sweatshirt fabric' among other features. Then if use my model on a new dress which has the attributes 'Nike', 'grey color', 'long sleeves' ... 'sweatshirt fabric'.... my model would correctly classify this as "sporty" too

Comment: Have you looked into fuzzy matching (excel)? There are lots of available code to do this online.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a standard classification, you can use naive Bayes or any other classification algorithm. But it is not the best way to label the data. If you used the predictions as labels to train another algorithm, the second algorithm would basically learn to imitate naive Bayes, you wouldn't learn much more than you learned from the initial 500 samples. As [noticed by Andrew Ng](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=06-AZXmwHjo) and many others, the quality of the data is one of the key factors to success. It is basically garbag-in garbage-out, if you start with poor labels, you don't have much chance to end up with a good model. It would be probably a better idea to spend a week manually labeling the data and two days on building the model, than the other way around. 9500 samples are not that many to label, if 500 samples would take you two hours, then all the data would take around a week. It would be time well spent, you additionally would learn more about potential problems with the data (quality, what is missing, etc) that could be useful when working on the model, or decision to gather more data.